# R barplot -- how to bars two bars of the same type with one label

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following R graph (ignore the fact that the first six bars don't have any label -- they have):
[image]

Made with plain R barplot:

```
bp <- barplot(raw_reord_perc$V2, names.arg = aux$Name, las=2, col = as.character(aux$color), ylab="Relative mapping #", cex.names=0.8)
text(bp, y=raw_reord_perc$V2, labels=aux$NucSource, pos=3, cex = 0.8)
```

I want the following two things:

1. Bars with the same label should have just one label (e.g. "H10"). Maybe with a horizontal bar above
2. Bars with the same label should have no space in between

**Edit:** I can also provide a column in the dataframe which say something about the grouping (Means in this example this vector would be: `c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10,11,12)`)

Comment: I'd suggest looking into `ggplot2`, it would make it easier to tune everything to your liking.

Comment: If you are not looking to create a ggplot as suggested, then you need to adjust what is in the `NucSource` which is labeling the bars at the top....

Comment: I am at the same stage now with ggplot2. How would you do that now? (Like "unifiy" bars with the same label -- so that they have no space in between and just one label)

Comment: I could also provide an extra grouping column to my raw data, saying which columns "belong together..."